# Android Fido2ApiClient Custom UI to unlock device

Tags: android, webauthn, fido

Using com.google.android.gms.fido.fido2.Fido2ApiClient#getSignPendingIntent, and start the intent with androidx.fragment.app.Fragment#startIntentSenderForResult, FIDO2 API for Android handles the biometric authentication with standard UI as below:
[image]

Is there a way to allow customization for the identity verification UI, instead of using the default UI as above, it allows developers to override with a custom UI.